# Regex validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, frontend

Minimum 3 characters, all small case, can use maximum of 2 numbers, no special characters allowed.
I tried using ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ but I'm unable to limit the numbers used

Can someone help me.

Comment: Is *can use maximum of 2 numbers* means that no numbers, one number, and two numbers is a valid option?

Comment: This is way better expressed as not 1 regex, but several validation statements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead assertion to rule out more than 3 digits:

```
/^(?!(?:.*\d+){3,})[a-z0-9]{3,}$/
```

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `(?!(?:.*\d+){3,})` assert that 3 or more digits do NOT occur
- `[a-z0-9]{3,}` then match 3 or more lowercase letters or digits
- `$` end of the string

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKIlrZ/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use check if there are at least 3 allowed characters, and then match 0, 1 or 2 digits.

```
^(?=[A-Za-z\d]{3})[A-Za-z]*(?:\d[A-Za-z]*){0,2}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[A-Za-z\d]{3})` Positive lookahead, assert 3 allowed chars
- `[A-Za-z]*` Match optional chars A-Za-z
- `(?:\d[A-Za-z]*){0,2}` Repeat 0-2 times matching a single digit and optional chars A-Za-z
- `$` End of string

See the matches on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9mICMH/1).